# Why does the LCD impede the ESP8266 NodeMCU initialization?

Tags: arduino, circuit-analysis, lcd, esp8266

I have  a very  simple setup on  a breadboard  that connects
a  Lolin  v3  NodeMCU  ESP8266  with a  16x02  LCD.  No  I2C
communication, I'm doing with  directly with Arduino IDE and
the [*LiquidCrystal*](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal) library.

For some reason when I  disconnect the LCD *Vdd* and connect
it after the MCU has  booted everything works fine. My power
supply indicates it draws ~70mA  during boot and then lowers
the current. However  if I leave the LCD  connected and turn
on the power  supply, the MCU won't boot and  the circuit is
stuck drawing 40mA with the  LCD showing blocks on the first
line at 50% contrast.

How can I fix this?

Here's how I setup my wiring:

[image: Wiring]

And my code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(D8, D7, D6, D5, D4, D3);

void setup(void) {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

void loop(void) {
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
  delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: I don't see any power supply decoupling capacitors.

Comment: @Andyaka how can I add them?

Comment: this may help ... https://zoetrope.io/tech-blog/esp8266-bootloader-modes-and-gpio-state-startup/

Comment: @jsotola Ah, that's it! Thank you very much. Since I have connections to spare I simply replaced the three GPIO pins 0, 2 ad 15 for the other remaining free pins and it works flawlessly. Do you want to post this as an answer? I think it could be useful to someone in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certains pins of the ESP are boot mode selection straps, and are internally weakly pulled high or low to boot normally, but these can be overridden externally to select other boot modes (to load firmware etc).

The LCD data, R/W and RS pins all have internal weak pull-ups to LCD supply voltage. These weak pull-ups of the LCD module override the weak pull-downs of the ESP, and select a boot mode where it does not boot normally.

What is even worse, is that the ESP pins are rated for 3.3V IO voltages, and the LCD pull-ups try to pull them to 5V. The current is very small due to the pull-up resistances are generally quite high, but still this should not be done for long-term reliability.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I had just finished reading the article posted in the commends and avoiding the GPIO 0, 2 and 15 did the trick of letting it boot normally. On the other hand, I'm now thinking about the long-term reliability you mentioned. I was wondering if there is a way around it. Any pointers to the right direction are greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: It depends which way you want to solve it. One way is to use an LCD module that works with 3.3V so they have the same supply. Another way is to do some kind of level conversion between the chips, and that can be done in many ways like a buffer chip or FET pass gate.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: the question was about esp8266, not esp32

Comment: @Juraj fixed, but this is a general concept, it does not have to be an ESP at all - many MCUs have special bootstrap pins which must be connected with care or it won't boot.

Answer (score -1):

Add diode before VDD of the LCD (Anode in +5V and Cathode in VDD of LCD)

Comment: That does not explain what the problem is and why would a diode on VDD fix this. It would still pull the IO pins high and prevent booting. So it would not work.